# adding action listener to an image

Tags: java, swing

I insert an image to a `JPanel`.  I write this code.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    img1=getToolkit().getImage("/Users/Boaz/Desktop/Piece.png");
    g.drawImage(img1, 200, 200,null);

}
```

I want to add an action listener to that picture, but it does not have an `addActionListener()` method.  How can I do that without putting the image in a button or label?

Comment: 1) For painting an image, a `JComponent` is all that is needed. 2) For either `JComponent` or `JPanel`, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)` 3) Do not try to load images within the paint method.  Load it in the `init()` or during construction and store it as a class level attribute.  4) The `Toolkit` image loading method requires a `MediaTracker`.  Use `ImageIO.read(File)` for a way to guarantee the image is loaded. 5) Swap `null` for `this` in the `drawImage()` method.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options.

**Use a `MouseListener` directly in the `JPanel`**

A simple but dirty way would be to add an [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) directly to the [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) in which you overrode the [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method, and implement a [`mouseClicked`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method which checks if the region where the image exists has been clicked.

An example would be something along the line of:

```
class ImageShowingPanel extends JPanel {

  // The image to display
  private Image img;

  // The MouseListener that handles the click, etc.
  private MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      // Do what should be done when the image is clicked.
      // You'll need to implement some checks to see that the region where
      // the click occurred is within the bounds of the `img`
    }
  }

  // Instantiate the panel and perform initialization
  ImageShowingPanel() {
    addMouseListener(listener);
    img = ... // Load the image.
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

*Note: An `ActionListener` can't be added to a `JPanel`, as a `JPanel` itself does not lend itself to create what is considered to be "actions".*

**Create a `JComponent` to display the image, and add a `MouseListener`**

A better way would be to make a new subclass of [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) whose sole purpose is to display the image. The `JComponent` should size itself to the size of the image, so that a click to any part of the `JComponent` could be considered a click on the image. Again, create a `MouseListener` in the `JComponent` in order to capture the click.

```
class ImageShowingComponent extends JComponent {

  // The image to display
  private Image img;

  // The MouseListener that handles the click, etc.
  private MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      // Do what should be done when the image is clicked.
    }
  }

  // Instantiate the panel and perform initialization
  ImageShowingComponent() {
    addMouseListener(listener);
    img = ... // Load the image.
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }

  // This method override will tell the LayoutManager how large this component
  // should be. We'll want to make this component the same size as the `img`.
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
  }
}
```

Comment: Going by the @user650679 history, it seems your answer won't be acknowledged/accepted in near future :). Though my vote of +1.

Comment: @Favonius: Hopefully this answer could help others in the future as well. Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: your code doesn't follow your description (fortunately :-) a) it correctly overrides _paintComponent_ (vs. paint stated in first example) b) it correctly _uses_ a MouseListener (vs. implemented stated)

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for pointing out the mismatch between the description and code. It's been a while, but I've made some changes to address the issue. :)

Comment: I want to add multiples images in a screen and make each of them clickable..so I would have to make those many JComponents?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put the image into a JLabel. When you use the program, it appears to just be the image, you can't tell its in a JLabel. Then just add a MouseListener to the JLabel.

Comment: the question specifically asks how to do it without putting it into a label, so your response would be best as a comment, not an answer.